# site-package error that only happen in gitlab ci

Tags: python-3.x, gitlab-ci, alpine-linux

I have a weird error that only happen when running inside gilab CI

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/builds/myfolder/myproject/my file.py", line 30, in makeHttpCall
    response = requests.get('https://some.url', headers=headers, timeout=120)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 530, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 643, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/responses.py", line 733, in unbound_on_send
    return self._on_request(adapter, request, *a, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/responses.py", line 680, in _on_request
    match, match_failed_reasons = self._find_match(request)
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable CallbackResponse object
```

Looking at python3.8/site-packages/responses.py it is doing the following

```
def _find_match(self, request):
    found = None
    found_match = None
    match_failed_reasons = []
    for i, match in enumerate(self._matches):
        match_result, reason = match.matches(request)
        if match_result:
            if found is None:
                found = i
                found_match = match
            else:
                # Multiple matches found.  Remove & return the first match.
                return self._matches.pop(found), match_failed_reasons
        else:
            match_failed_reasons.append(reason)
    return found_match, match_failed_reasons
```

The CI container is running alpine:3.12

Is there anything I can do to fix the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there are failures with latest responses library (0.12.1):
https://github.com/getsentry/responses/issues/358, try skipping responses version 0.12.1.